# Llamar varios stored procedures dentro de otro

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, plsql

Tengo una duda respecto a cómo llamar a varios stored procedures dentro de otro en Oracle. He intentado llamarlos de la siguiente forma, pero solo me ejecuta el primero. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer la llamada para que se ejecuten los tres? Estoy usando Oracle PL/SQL. La consulta si funciona, ya la ejecute por separado.

```
    PROCEDURE SP_NOMBRESP(P_EXITO     OUT NUMBE
                          P_ERROR        OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  V_CURSOR  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  V_EXITO1     NUMBER;
  V_ERROR1    VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN

        OPEN V_CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM 
           (SELECT NUMERO FROM
           TABLA1, TABLA2
           WHERE 
           TABLA1.PK = TABLA2.PK
           AND NOT (ABLA2.DATO = 1
                           AND TABLA2.DATO2 != 'X'
                           AND ABLA1.DATO3 = 'ALGO'))
            UNION
           (SELECT TABLA3.DATO FROM
               TABLA3, TABLA2
               WHERE 
             NOT (TABLA2.DATO1 = 1
               AND TABLA2.DATO2 != 'X'
               AND TABLA3 = 'ALGO')
             AND TXWV152_TABLA3.PK = TABLA2.PK);

             PG_PAQUETE.MY_SP1(V_CURSOR, V_EXITO1, V_ERROR1);
            PG_PAQUETE.MY_SP2(V_CURSOR, V_EXITO1, V_ERROR1);
            PG_PAQUETE.MY_SP3(V_CURSOR, V_EXITO1, V_ERROR1);
            PG_PAQUETE.MY_SP4(V_CURSOR, V_EXITO1, V_ERROR1);

        P_EXITO := 0;
        P_ERROR :=  'EJECUCIÓN EXITOSA';

        EXCEPTION 
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
        P_EXITO := 1;
        P_ERROR :=  SQLERRM;

END SP_NOMBRESP;
```

Comment: Hola MMora. ¿Puedes por favor incluir el código completo del stored procedure? Solo nos estás dando una vista parcial, y tal vez al verlo completo podamos determinar si hay un problema.

Comment: usa packages.
Aquí te dejo la información [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/packages.htm][1]

Comment: Hola MMora. Gracias por agregar la información. ¿Puedes explicarnos qué sucede actualmente con las llamadas aparte de la primera? Así como lo tienes, todos se ejecutarían, a menos que estés recibiendo algún error. Pero eso no lo has especificado.

Comment: Lo que hice fue meter todo en el mismo stored ya que usaban los mismos parametros de entrada

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar otros procedimientos almacenados desde uno padre por decirlo de una forma, debes agregar la siguiente linea de codido dentro del SP principal:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN SP_1; END;';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN SP_2; END;';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN SP_3; END;';

Debes manejar bien las excepciones en caso de que alguno te arroje un error y te sea fácil corregirlo.

Si lo que quieres es unir 3 procedimientos almacenados en uno solo, debes poner el código de estos, si no es difícil que te podamos prestar ayuda.

Comment: No, no hay necesidad de usar SQL dinámico por medio del `execute immediate`. Las llamadas tal como las tiene OP deberían funcionar correctamente. El problema que tiene es otro.